# Azure AD B2C - Privileged Identity Management

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Do anyone know if we can use Privileged Identity Management in Azure AD B2C tenants?

I have tried to Google this without any success.

We would like to utilize PIM to have developers for example requesting access before creating Application Registrations and similar in the B2C tenants.

From Azure Portal, we have configured "Pricing tier = PremiumP2".

Still, within the B2C tenant in the PIM view, we get the message "The tenant needs an AAD Premium 2 license."

[image: Azure Portal - PIM View]

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment like below:***

> **Note** that: Azure AD B2C currently doesn't support Privileged Identity Management. Only Azure AD with Premium P2 license has PIM.

[image]

Alternatively, you can create custom policies to with specific rules:

[image]

Otherwise, make use of **Identity Governance** which provides security like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Microsoft Entra Identity Governance documentation - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/governance/)

Comment: Can you use Identity Governance?

Tried to make an Access Package, but it "Next" is greyed out.

Also when trying to create a new Catalog, it just spins when hitting create.

If it is not supposed to be used, I do not understand why they do not just block/remove the pages from the B2C tenants to avoid confusion.